# C# error with a declared variable in an if statement

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding. I'm taking a C# class and am trying to code a app in Visual Studio. In the image below on line 45 is the error: Use of unassigned local variable "caloriesFromFat". I have declared it and on line 37 I assigned it a value with: "caloriesFromFat = fatGrams * fatGram_Rate;"

How do I solve this. I know it should be simple, but I do not know and have not found an answer yet.
Thank you for any help.

[image: C# variable error]

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. Paste the **text** in the post.

Comment: The assignment only happens, when the condition of the surrounding `if` is true. In any other case it remains unassigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to give `caloriesFromFat` a value when initiating or at least before trying to access its value on line `45`. In your code it is conditional if the variable `caloriesFromFat` is assigned or not. For your exact problem, you'll need to do something like this while creating the variable.

```cs
double fatGrams, totalCalories, caloriesFromFat = 0, percentCaloriesFromFat;
```

---

Additionally while taking a look at your code, it seems that something is wrong with your code logic, but this is only a vague guess on the first look at your code.

Comment: percentCaloriesFromFat = ((fatGrams * fatGram_Rate) / totalCalories);                    This is what I did to get it to work before your comment. But yours is much more simpler and common sense. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, I am try now to convert the answer from a decimal to a double or int. My numbers are 8 fat grams, 200 calories. Being the conversion for Calories from fat is (fat grams * 9) (8*9=72) and the conversion for Percent of calories from fat is: Calories from fat (72) / Total calories (200) = 0.36. Which MATH function should I use to get to 36%? I've tried a couple but they don't seem to change the answer. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: @SteveE. You just want to convert the `0.36` to `36%`?

Comment: yes, please. I've tried: int val1 = Decimal.ToInt32(dec1); and a couple MATH options like MATH.round, but I can't seem to figure out which one to use.

Comment: @SteveE. what about `Math.Round((72d / 200d, 2) * 100) + "%"`?

Comment: PERFECT!!  percentCaloriesFromFatResultsLabel.Text = Math.Round((72d / 200d) * 100) + "%" + " of calories are from fat.";                                                           Gives me the 36% I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: I will be glad to if you can tell me how that is done. I've clicked the check mark a couple of times, it does not seem to want to stay green.

Answer (score 0):

The first `if` condition will not initialize your `caloriesFromFat` variable in some circumstances (circumstances dictated by Your condition), so the compiler in order to prevent an Exception during runtime (because You cannot divide `caloriesFromFat = null; //non numeric` by a `double` value, it will retrieve an `"Use of Unassigned Local variable"` error before code compilation. It's just a smart way to prevent program crashes.
So initialize Your variable like:

```
double caloriesFromFat = 0;
```

and You should be ok.
This will prevent Your code to crash during execution, otherwise 0 and null are non compatible (different) values.